# visual studio typescript package not found installed through 'yarn' on the custom folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, yarnpkg

I developed some typescript modules. these modules need some typings (e.g jquery). something like this

```
private GetModal(id: string): JQuery<HTMLElement> {
    let $modal = this.getDiv("modal fade");
    $modal.attr("id", id);
    $modal.attr("aria-hidden", "true");
    return $modal;
}
```

so I install @types/jquery package through Yarn and I changed the package folder in .yarnrc file

```
--modules-folder wwwroot/lib
```

all packages were installed on wwwroot/lib folder, but the typescript compiler could not find those and these errors were thrown

```
TS2304:(TS) cannot find name 'JQuery'
```

This library compiled successfully on Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.x and it faileds after I upgraded to 17.7.x

Comment: Did you adjust your tsconfig?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes

Comment: Please share it